# How many different roots does $p(x) = x^{12}+2x^{6}+1 \in \mathbb{F}_3[x]$ have?

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, roots, extension-field, group-homomorphism

I want to find out how many different roots does $p(x) = x^{12}+2x^{6}+1 \in \mathbb{F}_3[x]$ have (not necessarily in $\mathbb{F}_3$, but in an body that has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_3$), where $\mathbb{F}_3$ is the finite body with $3$ elements ($\cong \mathbb{Z}_3$).
$p'(x)=12x^{11}+12x^{5} \equiv 0$ so $p(x)$ has roots of multiplicity $\geq 2$. I actually know that the roots with multuplicity $\geq 2$ are the zeroes of g.c.d$(p(x), p'(x))$ = g.c.d$(p(x), 0)=p(x)$. Therefore $p(x)$ only has roots with multiplicity $\geq 2$.
$p(x)$ doesn't have any roots in $\mathbb{F}_3$ so I have to build a body where $p(x)$ has at least a root. For example
$$\mathbb{F}_3[T]/\langle T^{12}+2T^6+1\rangle$$
I know that here $\overline{T}$ is a root. Using Frobenius' homomosphism I get that $\overline{T}^3, \overline{T}^9, \overline{T}^{27} = 2\overline{T}^9$ are roots. If I use Frobenius once again, I go back to $\overline{T}^9$. Does this mean I've found all the roots? How can I be sure there aren't any more roots?

Comment: Why don't you just count them all? there are only three elements for them to be. $p(0) = 1$ and $p(\pm 1) = 0$ so there are two roots $1,-1$.

Comment: @fleablood I am not looking for roots in $\mathbb{F}_3$, but rather in any body that contains a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_3$

Comment: You can't use Frobenius quite like that, because $T^{12}+2T^6+1$ is not irreducible, and hence the quotient ring is not a field.

Comment: By the way,, in English it is called *a field*. I know that in German it is *Körper* and in French something similar :-)

Comment: Hint: As you seem to be familiar with Frobenius, hence Freshman's dream, why don't you check what $(x^2+1)^6$ is equal to in $\Bbb{F}_3[x]$.

Comment: LOL @Dietrich. In Finnish the algebraic object is called *kunta* that more commonly means *Gemeinde* or *municipality*.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know. My translator gives "Galois ala" for "finite body".

Comment: *Kenttä* is in use in Finnish math/physics speak also. It is the appropriate term when describing *vector fields* (so *vektorikenttä*). I'm afraid I don't know what that is called in German. Pretty much all the mathematical German I have ever needed has been algebra/number theory.

Comment: In German it is just "Vektorfeld". Galois field is "endlicher Körper".

Comment: Thanks @Dietrich. One of my teachers (who speaks rather fluent German otherwise) claimed that *Galois Feld* is an ok German term for a finite field. I was a bit surprised, but haven't checked.

Comment: It [does check out](https://deacademic.com/dic.nsf/dewiki/492894)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
In $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$
$$p(x) = x^{12}+2x^{6}+1 = (x^{6} + 1)^2$$
How many roots do you expect to find in a splitting field, counting multiplicity?